# Open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: general-topology

I am reading a text on algebraic topology and I got confused with a small detail saying that if $f: \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^n$ with $m < n$, then $\mathbb{R}^m$ is homeomorphic to the set of $\mathbb{R}^n$ whose $n-m$ last coordinates are zero, this set is not open, because its complement is. Why is the complement of this set open?

Comment: Try with some low dimensions to see what happens: the complement of the $x$-axis is open in $\Bbb R^2$ and in $\Bbb R^3$, and the complement of the $xy$-plane is open in $\Bbb R^3$. Can you prove this? Them you're really close to a general proof.

Comment: Alternatively, the set you describe is the intersection of the kernel of finitely many (continuous) projection maps. Hence it is closed.

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan can you explain this more carefully?

Answer (score 1):

Define $$g: \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^n; \qquad (x_1,...,x_n)\mapsto (x_1,...,x_{n-m},0,...,0).$$

We have that $g$ is continuous and $Kern(g)=g^{-1}\{0\}=\Bbb \{0\}^{n-m}\times \Bbb R^m$.

Recall that the continuous preimage of closed sets is closed.

Answer (score 1):

Take $p=(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ in the complement $C$. Being in the complement means that $x_i\neq0$ for some $i\in\{m+1,\ldots,n\}$. Consider the open ball $B_{|x_i|}(p)$. If $q=(y_1,\ldots,y_n)\in B_{|x_i|}(p)$, then$$\sqrt{\sum_{j=1}^n|y_j-x_j|^2}<|x_i|$$and therefore $|y_i-x_i|<|x_i|$. But then $y_i\neq0$ and so $q\in C$ too. Since this occurs for each $q\in B_{|x_i|}(p)$, $B_{|x_i|}(p)\subset C$ and so $C$ is an open set.

Comment: Can you explain why is the complement defined like that?

Comment: @Roma_Rayado I did *not* define the complement like that. By definition, the complement of a subset $X$ of $\Bbb R^n$ is the set $\{v\in\Bbb R^n\mid v\notin X\}$. What I observed is that, if$$X=\{(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_m,0,0,\ldots,0)\mid x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_m\in\Bbb R\},$$then$$X^\complement=\bigl\{(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)\in\Bbb R^n\mid x_i\ne0\text{ for some }i\in\{m+1,\ldots,n\}\bigr\}.$$

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly the subset you are describing is simply equal to

$$\mathbb{R}^{m}\times\{0\}^{n-m}\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$$

Obviously this subset is closed as a product of closed subsets of $\mathbb{R}$. Hence the complement is open.